# How to post array as form data in Angular Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working in Angular 8 and is using web.api in .net core 2.2

I have a form including some "regular" inputs, a file and multi selectable checkboxes.

The problem is the multi selectable checkboxes, that I turn into an array of numbers. Before I post the data to the server, I Convert my FormGroup into FormData and add the file manually and also the array of ints from the multiselectable checkboxes:

```
data.append('locationsSecondaryIds',
    new Blob( [ JSON.stringify(this.profilePersonalData.locationsSecondaryIds)], { type : 'application/json' } ) );
    if (this.file) {
        data.append('document', this.file, this.file.name);
    }
```

locationsSecondaryIds is a number[].

I have also tried leaving out the Blob and just send it as [1,1], but when the server gets to the server it can't convert it to a List

Any good suggestions?

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Comment: can you explain more what you are trying to do? are you getting multiple selected checkboxes value as array or not? and if array is getting then you have to append array data with form data and then want to send data to server?

Comment: Thank very much for your reply.
The issue is receiving the array on the server when posting it as formdata ([FromForm]), and I an doing this because I also are sending a file.

Comment: Type of data you are sending from client side must be handled by server same type of data too. for example if your are sending `Application/Json` type of data from client than server must have settings for that data to handle it properly . same for blob type too

Comment: It is working fine as long as I don't include the array. In the Api I am using        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same scenario and here is how I did.

**My component.ts File in Angular:**

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Parameter1', "Some String Value");
formData.append('Parameter2', this.currentUserId.toString());
for (const index in this.arrayValues) 
{
    // instead of passing this.arrayValues.toString() iterate for each item and append it to form.
    formData.append(`ArrayValue[${index}]`,this.arrayValues[index].toString());
}
for (const file of this.importedFiles)
{
    formData.append('Files', file);
}
```

Now post it to asp.net core web api and it should work.

**My server side C# Class:**

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public int Parameter2 { get; set; }
    public string[] ArrayValue { get; set; }
    public IFormFile[] Files { get; set; }
}
```

> **Note:** Make sure to decorate your parameter with `[FromForm]`in your action method.

**Asp.Net Core Web Api Controller action method:**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeMethod([FromForm] SomeClass someClass)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the Files always come as null... do you have any idea as to why this could be happening? I used console.log() before adding it to the FormData and they look fine (I'm using the type File for the files in angular).

Comment: the `IFormFile[]` property in server side should have name as `Files` exactly. If you have different name it won't bind and it will be null.

Comment: Latter I discovered that the problem was that I was trying to do it in a nested object that for some reason doesn't work with the File, when I used the parent object to receive the Files it worked, thanks

Comment: @fingers10 It works for me. Did you ever try with a object instead of number?

Comment: @SJNE please can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for picking multiple checkbox values and appending it in a form data.
On submit button:

```
let subs = [];
subs = this.skillForm.value.subjects; // here subject refers to multi select dropdown
let subString = subs.toString(); // you can let the values to be int as per your DB 
//column
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('values',subString);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply!
When sending it like you suggested I get the following respose from the server
{"errors":{"LocationsSecondaryIds":["The value '1007,1006,1005' is not valid."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"8000001c-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}

Comment: you need to check what does your column accepts string/int values. change accordingly.

Comment: What column? The object on the api that the array is converted to have is a List<int>

Comment: If it's int you don't need to convert it to string type. :)

Comment: If I don't convert it to string I get: 
Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Now I have tried changing the datatype on the api to List<string>, and then my array is passed as on element in the List<string> ("1007,1009"). It is like I some how need to inform the server that it is an array? int the request to the server it looks like: Name: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="locationsSecondaryIds" value: 1007, 1009

Comment: Has your problem been solved or still stuck with it?

Comment: Still stuck :-|

Comment: First tell me are you able to get desired values from the checkbox?

Comment: Yes I have the values from the checkboxes, the issue is receiving them on the server.

Comment: Make sure type is same on the server

Comment: I am sending an array of numbers: 1007, 1009 also tried [1007, 1009]. And on the server I am expecting a List<int>

Comment: List refers to array so your data must be [1007, 1008, 1009] int Array in order to accept values. If it is not accepting please debug on your back end side.

Comment: In my post it look like this: ------WebKitFormBoundaryMkzlrEnkbXgBBaBN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="locationsSecondaryIds"

[1001,1008]
I have tried changing it to an array of int, array of strings. If it is an array of strings, it is just received as one element in the array :-|

Answer (score 0):

The answer from fingers10 worked for me.  For my code, I had to add an array of objects, to do this I used his answer with the following code.

```
    for (const index in voteData.feedMessageTags) {
        // instead of passing this.arrayValues.toString() iterate for each item and append it to form.
        formData.append(`feedMessageTags[${index}].key`, voteData.feedMessageTags[index].key);
        formData.append(`feedMessageTags[${index}].value`, voteData.feedMessageTags[index].value);
    }
```